# How to evenly space each container of toggle button to fit screen and make selected container be rounded in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, togglebutton

I want to create toggle buttons and evenly space each element in the list of toggle buttons and make each selected button rounded like this,
[image]

I've tried using boxconstraints property, width property, margin property and the rest,
But this is what I'm getting, I've tried every other thing but I can't get it, this is what I'm getting
[image]

This is the code I'm using

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TestingScreen> createState() => _TestingScreenState();
}

class _TestingScreenState extends State<TestingScreen> {
  List<bool> _isSelected = [true, false, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 100),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Time',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            ToggleButtons(
              color: Color(0xff001666),
              fillColor: Color(0xff001666),
              selectedColor: Colors.white,
              children: [
                ToggleButton(name: '1D'),
                ToggleButton(name: '1W'),
                ToggleButton(name: '1M'),
                ToggleButton(name: '1Y'),
              ],
              isSelected: _isSelected,
              onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  for (int i = 0; i < _isSelected.length; i++) {
                    if (i == newIndex) {
                      _isSelected[i] = true;
                    } else {
                      _isSelected[i] = false;
                    }
                    print(_isSelected);
                  }
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ToggleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  const ToggleButton({Key? key, required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        name,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `renderBorder: false,` property to remove the ash colored border and `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),` to make the round circled border in the outside and make the shape you can use `constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(height: 25,width: 34),` to get the the exact size of the height and the width.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER3WB.png)

but to get the exact result you have to use `Inkwell()` or `ElvatedButton()` or `IconButton()` bcz there isnt any property to use the `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),` for the each of the icons in the buttons as showed in the picture.
Hope it will work for you.